# ColdFusion - Duplicate POST Being Fired

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I have a very strange thing happening and cannot seem to track it down. I have a simple CFM with a simple form, the user presses the submit button, the page POSTs to itself and then calls a CFC function with a `<cfinvoke>`.  The function that is being invoked has a single `<cfstoredproc>` call to Oracle.  That Oracle procedure is supposed to create around 3,000+ records.  But it's creating exactly double that amount.  I put a `<cflog>` right before the `<cfstoredproc>` call and there are 2 entries being created.  So this function is being fired a second time somehow.  Same user, same SessionID, different ThreadID.  I have no idea where this second call is coming from.

- I am pressing the button only once.
- I watched the network traffic, I only see one POST.

I put a `<cflock>` around the `<cfstoredproc>` call and that fixed the problem, only 3000+ recs are now created.  But now I get a lock timeout error for this mysterious second call.

Another strange thing is that the `<cflock>` has a timeout of 30 seconds.  But the `<cflog>` shows only 1 entry initially, then exactly 60 seconds later the second log entry appears and the `<cflock>` error happens.  I dropped the `<cflock>` timeout down to 15 seconds and the results were still the same.  Why is this second mysterious call being logged exactly 1 minute after the first one every time?

I'm running ColdFusion 10,0,13,287689.

```
"Severity","ThreadID","Date","Time","Application","Message"

"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-9","06/26/14","14:59:34",,"D:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\logs\cbruserwo_cfc.log initialized"
"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-9","06/26/14","14:59:34","xxx","USERA // USERA // 1958938 // lockname: B-100139230442054"
"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-7","06/26/14","15:00:35","xxx","USERA // USERA // 1958938 // lockname: B-100139230442054" <-- the mysterious one, comes in 1 minute later

"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-12","06/26/14","15:08:36","xxx","USERA // USERA // 1958938 // lockname: B-100139230442054"
"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-5","06/26/14","15:09:37","xxx","USERA // USERA // 1958938 // lockname: B-100139230442054" <-- the mysterious one, comes in 1 minute later

"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-1","06/26/14","15:19:54","xxx","USERA // USERA // 1958938 // lockname: B-100139230442054"
"Information","ajp-bio-8012-exec-7","06/26/14","15:20:57","xxx","USERA // USERA // 1958938 // lockname: B-100139230442054" <-- the mysterious one, comes in 1 minute later
```

I am using an Application.cfc with both the `onRequest` and `onCFCRequest` methods (along with the other usual ones).

**Some of the code ...**

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="create" access="public">
...removed some trivial code...

<!--- START: debug this craziness --->
<cflock timeout="30" name="A-#form.cbrorderunid#">
    <cfif not isdefined("session.cbruserwo_cfc.calledcnt")>
        <cfset session.cbruserwo_cfc.calledcnt = 1>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset session.cbruserwo_cfc.calledcnt = session.cbruserwo_cfc.calledcnt+1>
    </cfif>

    <cflog file="cbruserwo_cfc" text="#session.sv.un# // #session.sv.fullname# // #session.sv.csid# // lockname: B-#form.cbrorderunid#">

    <cfsavecontent variable="xxx">
        <cfoutput>
        session.cbruserwo_cfc.calledcnt: #session.cbruserwo_cfc.calledcnt#<br>
        CGI: <cfdump var="#cgi#">
        FORM: <cfdump var="#form#">
        URL: <cfdump var="#url#">
        ARGUMENTS: <cfdump var="#arguments#">
        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cffile action= "write" file="D:\temp\cbruserwo_cfc.html" addNewLine="no" output="#xxx#">
</cflock>
<!--- END: debug this craziness --->

<!--- The debug code above shows another POST/call/request something being made, but the network traffic shows only 1 POST happening --->

<cflock timeout="30" name="B-#form.cbrorderunid#">
    <cfstoredproc>
        <!---
        This is the call that would do the 3000+ inserts, omitted contents, irrelavent to question.
        The cflock around it fixes the duplicate records from being created, but now I get lock timeout
        errors from this mysterious second request.
        --->
    </cfstoredproc>
</cflock>
 ...removed some trivial code...
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

**UPDATE...**

Some people ask for all the code and some are saying don't post all the code, so I don't know what the heck you guys want.  I admit this is a weird one.  We very recently added the application.cfc->onRequest function.  Not sure if that has anything to do with it.  But all it does at this time is this...

```
<cffunction name="onRequest" access="public">
    <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true" />

    <!--- Make these functions globally accessible --->
    <cfset structAppend(url, createObject("component", "lib_globalfunctions"))>

    <!--- Include the requested page. --->
    <cfinclude template="#ARGUMENTS.TargetPage#" />
</cffunction>
```

I also inspected all the Apache ssl_requestlog's, there is only one post happening.  That's why I didn't show any of my html, form, button, submit code.

I'll try ripping out all the customtags / proprietary code and come up with a bare bones generic replication of the bug.  If I can I'll rewrite this question and post that.  It'll take some time.  Was just wondering if anyone had heard of a bug like this before, looks like no one has, thanks.

**MORE UPDATEs...**

It is looking less and less like a ColdFusion issue.

Each bullet point is consistently repeatable for each user.

- ME - Latest version of Chrome, the second mysterious request happens.
- ANOTHER USER - Same building, same version of Chrome, no second request.
- ME - IE10, no second request.
- ANOTHER USER - Outside the building, IE10, the second mysterious request happens.

Comment: Split the form processing into a separate file: form.cfm > form_processing.cfm. Then redirect back to form.cfm if that is your workflow. See if the code fires twice under that setup. Also, are you using JavaScript to submit the form? I've seen cases where the JavaScript submit() fires, but the normal form submit event also fires.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how people are supposed to help you with this when you've not posted any code..? Don't describe the code, just post it (or, preferably, a pared down reproduction case that demonstrates the issue).

Comment: I agree with @iKnowKungFoo once you split that pig up you'll likely find the problem. Also you should have put your code out here so we could help you more effectively. ;) It also makes for a good unit test to split out your code.  Just test your forms behavior and not the serverside events can help normalize your form. Maybe you have a duped form variable, dump out your form and abort like this `<cfdump var="#form#" abort>` I bet some mysteries will be revealed.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo, Thanks, doubt that's it.  I have 100s of pages setup this way, they all use the same code for the form, buttons, and submitting.  If that was the case I would see more than one POST.

Comment: @AdamCameron, I'll start posting the code, it's a lot, was really just wondering if anyone had heard of an anomaly or bug like this. I know you can't fix what you can't see :)

Comment: Show us the code in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.cfc/application.cfm and see if there is any manipulation for POST data in onRequest function.

Comment: Not that I can tell. I updated original question, added the onRequest function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps running behind a Barracuda firewall?  If so, it's likely how they handle "session timeouts". I ran into the exact issue and traced it back to the firewall.  Their default session timeout is 60 seconds, after which they send a 408 timeout error to the browser forcing it to send a second request.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: We do not use Barracuda.  Last I remember I started looking into something similar but for the webserver.  I was researching Apache to to see if it was doing something similar to what you described.  I had to move on to another task but when I come back to re-visit it I will update this question.  Thanks!